# How to put input/output redirection in your newly-created c shell?

Tags: c, linux, shell, io, io-redirection

I am wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction on how to do this?  For example, if I write "ls > contents.txt", I want the output of ls to be written into content.txt.

This is what I have so far.

```
 #include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void  parse(char *line, char **argv)
{
     while (*line != '\0') { 
          while (*line == ' ' || *line == '\t' || *line == '\n')
               *line++ = '\0';     
          *argv++ = line;          
          while (*line != '\0' && *line != ' ' && 
                 *line != '\t' && *line != '\n') 
               line++;            
     }
     *argv = '\0';               
}

void  execute(char **argv)
{
     pid_t  pid;
     int    status;

     if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {     
          printf("*** ERROR: forking child process failed\n");
          exit(1);
     }
     else if (pid == 0) {          
          if (execvp(*argv, argv) < 0) {     
               printf("*** ERROR: exec failed\n");
               exit(1);
          }

     }
     else {                                 
          while (wait(&status) != pid)      
               ;
     }
}
void main(char *envp[])
{
    char line[1024];
    char *argv[64];
    while (1){
      printf("shell>>");
      gets(line);
      printf("\n");
      parse(line, argv);
      if (strcmp(argv[0], "exit")==0)
    exit(0);
      execute(argv);
    }
}
```

Comment: this code block: 'while (*line == ' ' || *line == '\t' || *line == '\n')
               *line++ = '\0'; ' is terminating the line[], so the parse function will exit without having parsed anything beyond the first parameter (in this case, the 'ls')

Comment: this line: 'void main(char *envp[])' will not cleanly compile in linux.  suggest: int main(int argc, char* argv[], char *envp[])

Comment: Note that writing  your own shell could involve significant work.  For example "ls \*.gz >contents.txt" will not work as expected.  Wildcards will have no meaning when passed via exec.   It will say "no such file \*.xz" even if you have lots of .xz files in your directory, because ls is being asked to literally look for a file named "\*.xz"    Normally the shell first finds all the files matching the wildcard and then passes them as arguments to the command.  Most commands don't known how to expand wildcards themselves.

Comment: do you have an alternate suggestion of how to parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In between test for pid==0 and before you run execvp(), you want code like this:

```
int fd=open(outputfile,O_WRONLY|O_CREAT); 
dup2(fd,1);
```

This will essentially set the stdout for the program run by execvp() to be to this new file.    You will have to modify your parsing code to look for the ">" and parse what comes after it as a filename and store in outputfile. 
You'd also want to do some additional checking to make sure the new file opens OK, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to:

- check for `> [filename]` in the command passed
- if that is there, then open the relevant file for output, and use `dup2` to attach the fd you get to the `stdout` of the forked process.

That should be enough to point you in the right direction.